# Let $z=re^{i2\pi\theta}$ and $w=\lambda z+cz^2\bar{z}+\mathcal{O}(z^4)=\tilde{r}e^{i2\pi\psi}$, what is an $\mathcal{O}(r^3)$ approximation of $\psi$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z = re^{i2\pi \theta}$. Then consider the map
$$ z \mapsto \lambda z + c z^2 \bar{z} + \mathcal{O}(z^4).$$
Now under this map, $\theta$ is mapped to $\tilde{\theta}$. I am trying to find a third order accurate ($\mathcal{O}(z^3)$) approximation for $\tilde{\theta}$. Here $c$ is a complex number.

What I did so far. Neglecting the $\mathcal{O}(z^4)$ term we get 
$$ z  \mapsto   (\lambda r + cr^3)e^{i2\pi \theta}   , $$ 
as $z^2\bar{z} = r^3 e^{i4\pi \theta}e^{-i2\pi\theta}  =r^2z $. Then 
$$ \tilde{\theta}   =\arctan \left(  \frac{\Im (\lambda z + cr^2z)}{\Re(\lambda z + cr^2z)}   \right)    .$$
Now a second order accurate approximation of $\arctan(x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$. So 
$$ \tilde{\theta} = \frac{\Im (\lambda z + cr^2z)}{\Re(\lambda z + cr^2z)} + \mathcal{O}(r^3). $$

The expression I should get is 
$$ \theta \mapsto  \theta + \phi +\frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \Im\left(\frac{c}{\lambda} \right)r^2 +\mathcal{O}(r^3)\right) $$
with 
$\phi = \frac{1}{2\pi} \tan^{-1} \frac{\omega}{\alpha}$ with with $\omega =\Im (c)$ and $\alpha = \Re(c)$.

Some context, I am working through a book by Wiggins on dynamical systems. This section is about the Neimark Sacker bifurcation. He simply states the result without proof and I thought it would be easy to prove (maybe it is). I would also like to find the expression for what $r$ get mapped to.

EDIT: $\lambda $ is also a complex number.

Let $z=re^{i2\pi\theta}$ and $w=\tilde{r}e^{i2\pi \tilde{\theta}}$, what is $\tilde{\theta}$?